# How to link (a menu item) to the RSS feed?

Tags: routes, feeds, i18n-l10n, navigation

In our Drupal installation there is a menu item for the RSS feed, pointing to path *de/rss* for the German feed.

This path appears unchanged in the frontend and is invalid, hence results in a 404.

The correct URL is /de/rss.xml or just /rss.xml.

Weird thing is, that Drupal accepts the non-working path, while it rejects the correct ones:

> The path 'de/rss.xml' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

What's going on?

**Note**: I'm using the i18n module. And when I call /de/rss.xml it gets redirected to /rss.xml.

Comment: Are you using i18n module? Is your site in multiple languages?

Comment: Yes. And when I call /de/rss.xml it gets redirected to /rss.xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module, and after you have installed module [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable), you should enable the `i18n_variable` module (one of the i18n submodules that requires the Variable module, among others).

Then navigate to `/admin/config/regional/i18n/variable` (= the Variables tab within '
Multilingual settings'). There you'll be able to specify all sorts of variables for which you want multi language support enabled also, using an appropriate sub-tab there, such as for "Site information", "Menu settings", etc.). Within sub-tab **other**, there is also "RSS feed for front page" (=The RSS feed for the front page, default is rss.xml). That "other" sub-tab should be between "Menu Settings" (1st sub-tab) and "Site Information" (3rd sub-tab).

I'd be curious to hear if your issue is resolved after you enable that option (by checking the checkbox).

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. In *other* there's only _Pages or PHP code_. In the tab *Feed settings* there's only _Feed description_. I couldn't find _RSS feed for front page_ in any of the tabs /: Version is 7.35

Comment: Looks like we're making progress / coming close. I slightly enhanced my answer (added the 'i18n_variable' part of it). Can you confirm you have that submodule enabled also? And then provide another status update (comment)?

Comment: Module _Variable translation_ is enabled.

Comment: What's your answer to my PS in my comment in the question, ie: do you have only 1 language enabled (de) or maybe both "en" and "de" or so?

Comment: _de_ is default and _en_ is enabled as well.